# Eclipse Helios + BIRT 2.6 - Cannot add/create datasource

Tags: eclipse, datasource, birt

I cannot create any datasource including the "Classic Models Inc. Sample Database". I do not get any error on the UI but the data source does not get created / does not show up in the Data Explorer.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? How can I fix this?

TIA

Comment: Did you create a blank Reporting Project and add a blank report?  Then from there how did you go about adding the data source?  I have never seen this come up as an issue so perhaps with a little more background I can work to an answer with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this - I had to update some plugins and after that this started working fine.